# Lifting Functors to Adjoints

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

There are well-understood theorems that give sufficient conditions for a functor $R: D\to C$ to have a left adjoint.  For example, $R$ should preserve limits and $D$ should have nice categorical properties.

But there are situations in which $R$ does *not* preserve limits, yet it lifts to a right adjoint functor $R: D\to C'$, where $C'\to C$ is some nice projection of categories.

For example, if $R$ is the forgetful functor from the category of fields to the category of rings, then $R$ does not preserve products, but we can define $C'$ to be the category of pairs $(R,p)$, where $R$ is a ring and $p$ is a prime ideal of $R$.  Then the functor $R':D\to C'$ sending $k$ to $(k,(0))$ has a left adjoint sending $(R,p)$ to $Frac(R/p)$.

This has a natural description in terms of comma categories $(c/R)$, though I am not sure if this is fruitful to pursue.

I believe that this is a very general phenomenon, but I am short on both examples and theory.  Are there results or general constructions that begin to describe what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R : D \to C$ be any functor. Let $C'$ be the category of triples $(c, d, f)$ where $c \in C, d \in D$, and $f : c \to R(d)$ is a morphism; this is a certain comma category, as you say. It admits a projection to $C$ given by forgetting $d$ and $f$, and it also admits both a functor to and from $D$. The functor from $D$ is given by

$$R' : D \ni d \mapsto (R(d), d, \text{id}_{R(d)}) \in C'$$

and the functor $L : C' \to D$ is given by forgetting $c$ and $f$.

> **Claim:** $L \vdash R'$ is an adjunction.

*Proof.* We want to show that we have a natural bijection

$$\text{Hom}_D(d, d') \cong \text{Hom}_{C'}((c, d, f), (R(d'), d', \text{id}_{R(d')})).$$

This is just a matter of unwinding the definition of a morphism in $C'$. A morphism from $(c, d, f)$ to $(R(d'), d', \text{id}_{R(d')})$ consists of a morphism $g : c \to R(d')$ and a morphism $h : d \to d'$ such that

$$\left( c \xrightarrow{g} R(d') \right) = \left( c \xrightarrow{f} R(d) \xrightarrow{R(h)} R(d') \right).$$

This uniquely determines $g$ given $h$, and there is no condition on $h$. So we get a natural bijection to morphisms $d \to d'$ as desired. $\Box$

One way to think about this construction is to think about comma categories as a lax variant of [homotopy pullbacks](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+pullback) of spaces. Taking comma categories where one of the functors is the identity corresponds to taking homotopy pullbacks $D \times_C C'$ where $C' \to C$ is a homotopy equivalence, and in this case the projection to $D$ is also a homotopy equivalence. And it's natural to think of adjunctions as a lax variant of homotopy equivalences; for example, they induce homotopy equivalences on [nerves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(category_theory)).

Comment: Okay, this gives me some good ideas to digest.  My one concern is that this gives a category bigger than the one I'm looking for, e.g. I would like to identify the maps $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ through the map $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$.  More to the point, I would like a construction that is trivial when $R$ already has a left adjoint.  I assume that we can localize $C'$ to make this happen, but I feel that there should be a more intuitive explanation.

Comment: @Slade I was just puzzling through this also... The adjunction in your question is obtained by composing the one Qiaochu gives with an additional adjunction. Let $C'$ be the category in Qiaochu's answer and $C''$ the category in your question. Then the functor $C'\to C''$ given by $(A,k,f\colon A\to R(k)) \mapsto (A,\text{ker}(f))$ has a left adjoint $C''\to C$ given by $(A,p)\mapsto (A,\text{Frac}(A/p),g)$, where $g$ is the obvious map $A\to \text{Frac}(A/p)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman This is a good point.  This seems to arise from the following property: any morphism $R\to k$ from a ring to a field factors uniquely through some $R\to k'$ ($k'=Frac(R/p)$).  This is weaker than the assumption that there is a single such $k'$ for all morphisms from $R$ to a field, which is the universal property of the counit of an adjunction.  But it's quite a bit stronger than no assumptions at all.

Comment: I think that I can use this to answer my question.  When Qiaochu's $C'$ has the right kind of limits (namely, the coslice categories are filtered), Alex's adjunction can be produced by a localization via a calculus of right fractions.  More intuition for this would be nice, but I think this provides an adequate technical answer to the question as asked.